# Subversion & Custom Hosting

Tags: svn, hosting

I have been using BeansTalk to host my personal SVN repository and I am pretty satisfied with that. However, I have just subscribed a (shared) hosting plan for a personal website and I began wondering whether I can also use it to host my SVN repositories. Do I need to have SVN installed on the server? Or can I just create  a repository and throw all the files to a given directory on the server using, for example, TortoiseSVN?

Comment: Why the close vote, by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need access to a shell on the server, and be able to sudo, to be able to set up a SVN server on your web server. If you can do both of these, do a google search for instructions as there are thousands, if not millions of tutorials are available on the interweb.

Do no simply dump your repository files on your web server. That won't work.

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN is an SVN client. I communicates with a SVN server which stores and gets files to/from a repository. You thus need an SVN server on the server.